# Clone repos with a similar name

Tags: bash, git

I would like to do something like:

`git clone https://github.com/meteor{A,B,C,D}test`

but bash does not convert the `{}` into an each. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using `{A,B,C,D}` is valid, but it results in argument splitting. Meaning your command will be run as:

```
git clone https://github.com/meteorAtest https://github.com/meteorBtest https://github.com/meteorCtest https://github.com/meteorDtest
```

What you want is to run 4 different commands. One simple way to do this is a `for` loop.

```
for url in https://github.com/meteor{A,B,C,D}test; do git clone "$url"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
echo https://github.com/meteor{A,B,C,D}test | xargs -n 1 -d ' ' git clone
```

echo will expand it to 4 git url's and `git clone` will clone it